# Are Mainframe systems replacable?

Tags: mainframe

I'm actually working as a Developper on the mainframe field. Reading many documentations I understand that the real power of such systems is that they can treat many transactions (input/output) operation at the same time. They're also needed to keep high performances.

So I was wondering, aren't the modern systems capable of performing the same or even better?

Comment: Your question is too broad - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I suggest losing the Cobol and JCL tags as they will only get in the way of people searching for real problems.

Comment: I'm really tempted to suggest moving this to the Retrocomputing SE....

Comment: Flagged: it is impossible to answer this question without being opinionated. The comparison and 'replaceability' by performance alone makes no sense.

Comment: I'm not sure this needs to be flagged.  Its asking a question that many ask.  I think its good for information as this is a common mis-conception that allows for some to clarify (which should be based on objective criteria and not emotion I concur.) @HongOoi I think moving to retro would obscure an important technological point because its an issue that exists today.

Comment: @Hogstrom Stack Overflow was designed to avoid just this kind of open-ended wide-ranging discussions. While an interesting topic with important implications, this Question does not belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BasilBourque . I understand your PoV.  Technically it has to do with choosing a technology which makes it open-ended.  If folks feel it needs to be moved I'd support it.  I hear this question a lot and I thought it was useful.  If it moves to another forum and is still findable that would be fine as well.

Answer (score 4):

To correct some mis-understandings.

Mainframe hardware is not "old" -- it has had continuous development
and undergone a refresh cycle every two or three years. The chippery involved
is in some ways more advanced than x86 -- things like have a spare cpu on each
chip -- most of the differences are aimed at reliability and availability rather 
than raw performance.

Having said that both manufacturers are moving the same electrons around on the same silicon so actual per CPU performance is much the same.

Likewise mainframe software comes in two varieties "ancient" and "modern".
Some software like "CICS" was first developed in the 1970s and although it
is actively maintained it still has some of the original code.
Some software (IEBCOPY we are looking at you) was developed in the 1960s and was considered terrible even then has been left untouched for decades.

However zOS also runs a fully POSIX compliant UNIX shell in which you can run any compliant J2EE application or compile any C/C++ program to run in.

While a well set up x86 environment can match the raw processing power, they fall slightly behind when it comes to reliability and availability.

The main reason why so many large corporations stick with the mainframe is the large body of bespoke software written for COBOL/CICS, PL/1-IMS environments at a 
time when hardware was expensive and coding efficiency was at a premium.

So you could re-write an old COBOL/CICS application in Java/J2EE, but, you
would need about five times the raw processing power for the new system,
always assuming you could work out what business rules and logic was
embedded in the older system.

Answer (score 4):

There are many factors involved in choosing a platform.  The fact is that existing mainframes (generally IBM z/OS systems is what is implied) have a massive amount of existing programs, business processes, disaster recovery plans, etc. that would all need to be refactored.  Your talking about migrating existing applications based on runtimes that do not exist on other platforms.  Not to mention that massive amount of data that exists both transactionally and historically.

For instance, Customer Interactive Control System (CICS) uses a specific API called CICS EXEC where program calls, database interactions, internal programming facilities like queues exist.  All of these programs need to be re-written, ported and established by moving the programs, processes and data to new platforms.  Its rewriting 50 years of a business' investment.

This is inherently risky to a business.  You are disrupting existing operations and intellectual property and data to gain what?  The cost of any such move is massive and risky for what benefit?  It ends up being risk / reward.

Bear in mind, that there is a new legacy built on Windows and Linux that will likely be "disrupted" in the future and its not likely that one would move all those applications for the same reasons.

As @james pointed out, mainframes are close to, if not currently, the fastest single general computing platforms out there.  New hardware versions come out every two years and software is always being added to the platform, Java, Node, etc.  The platform continues to evolve.

Its a complicated subject and not as simple as "use other technology" to perform the same or better.  Its moving the programs, data and processes, which is really the hard part.

Answer (score 0):

"performing better" is highly unlikely because the mainframe segment is still highly relevant in business and its architectures are kept closely up-to-date with all evolutions both in hardware and [system] software.

"performing the same" is theoretically certainly possible, but it must be noted that some of the more popular mainframe architectures have significantly different hardware setups, e.g. the processors in z/OS systems are, comparatively, pathetically slow, but they delegate lots and lots of work to coprocessors, and it must also be noted that on the software side, mainframers tend to have a higher degree of "resource-awareness" than, eurhm, more "modern" developers.

That said, of course any answers to this question will necessarily be more opinion than hard-facts based, which makes it an unfortunate thing to ask here.

Comment: and the question is much to broad